# Android Studio 3.6.3 Update does not launch apk on click of "run" icon

Tags: android-studio

Recently i have updated my Android Studio to 3.6.3 and since then the "Run app" button does not result in installation and launch of Launcher activity.

Only the build happens successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

change installation options deploy to APK from app bundle or default APK

Comment: what do you mean ?